# SlidingDrawer Content touch not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I am using Sliding Drawer in my activity for giving some Interaction.

```
<SlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/sdDrawerLeft"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:content="@+id/sdLeftContent"
        android:handle="@+id/sdLeftHandle"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:rotation="180" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sdLeftHandle"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_rounded_corners_gray_right"
            android:rotation="180"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_arrow_left" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/sdLeftContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:rotation="180"
            android:weightSum="1" >

            <requestFocus />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgFavourite"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_weight=".1"
                android:background="@drawable/border_image"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_content_like" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgFolder"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_weight=".1"
                android:background="@drawable/border_image"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_content_add_folder" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgShare"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_weight=".1"
                android:background="@drawable/border_image"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_content_share" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgComment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_weight=".1"
                android:background="@drawable/border_image"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_content_comment" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </SlidingDrawer>
```

I am doing some operations on clicking on these Imageviews. But When I click on these ImageViews The screen behind sliding content gets touch event. I have made these imageviews clickable but not getting events like onClick and onTouch.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have added

`android:clickable="true"` for your `LinearLayout`. If this is desiarable

Try adding

`android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` `SlidingDrawer` tag,

and if this does not work, keep this as it is, and add,

```
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

for each of your `ImageView` which you made clickable.

it seems like its a question with a not so elegant solution. I was able to find a solution that intercept complete events over the window and act accordingly.

Please have a look at [the solution](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/fTtZ0-uwY-o) that I found

Comment: @unflagged.destination did you try removing `android:clickable="true"` from your `LinearLayout`?. Try  also making `ImageView`s `android:clickable=false`. A I can see the confusion is basically, android:clickable="true" in LinearLayout and again having clickable elements inside that